# Как восстановить одну базу из дампа?

Tags: mysql

Есть дамп нескольких баз, размер файла 2ГБ. Встала проблема восстановления одной базы из дампа. Если из консоли запустить восстановления из дампа, то он, наверное, восстановит все базы, а мне нужно восстановить только одну. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - восстановить на тестовый сервер и оттуда сделать дамп нужной базы.

А еще для восстановления больших дампов есть скриптик [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/). Восстанавливает очень быстро огромные файлы.

Comment: Не хотел возится с тестовым сервером, похоже придется. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Спасибо на хлеб не намажешь ;) Просто примите ответ, если устроил!

Answer (score 1):

БД, наверно, под Unix? Если вы можете посмотреть, с какой по какую строки идет ваша БД, то можете скормить `mysql` только указанную часть. Например, через `head`/`tail`:

```
tail +22 dump.sql | head -7 | mysql -uroot
```

где 22 - первая строка, 7 - количество строк.

Comment: База 2Гб, и просматривать ее нереально

Comment: не вручную же просматривать. `grep`, например, `USE {DB_NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

а разве дамп - это не "один большой скрипт"? может, можно его расковырять и достать нужный кусок?

Comment: Все верно, только вы попробуйте найти нужный кусок в текстовом файле размером 2Гб :D